# Rotina para baixar e descompactar arquivo zip no próprio servidor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, download, arquivo-zip

Estou precisando desenvolver em meu site (ASP.NET MVC) uma rotina que baixe de outro servidor um arquivo zip disponibilizado semanalmente e descompacte no meu próprio serviço de hospedagem.

Esta rotina pode ser acionada através de um button que verifique a disponibilidade do arquivo e execute o procedimento.

O arquivo zip é disponibilizado pela Caixa

Tenho a seguinte url
http://www.caixa.gov.br/Downloads/licitacoes-e-fornecedores-consultas-publicas/TR_Nova_Instantanea_v2.zip

Quero baixar este zip atraves da rotina e descompacta-la.

Estou tentando usar a biblioteca ZipFile, mas não obtive sucesso.

```
response.ContentType = "application/zip";
response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + outputFileName);
using (ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile()) {
  zipfile.AddSelectedFiles("*.*", folderName, includeSubFolders);
  zipfile.Save(response.OutputStream);
}
```

---

**Atualização**: Eu inseri seu código em uma nova Controller para executar este comando quando faço o acesso, ficando assim.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
   HttpClient web = new HttpClient();
   string url = "http://www.caixa.gov.br/Downloads/";
   url += "licitacoes-e-fornecedores-consultas-publicas/TR_Nova_Instantanea_v2.zip";
   byte[] data = await web.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
   System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("p.zip", data);
   ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory("p.zip", "./g");

    return View();
 }
```

Mas quando chega nesta linha parece que o arquivo não foi baixado e dá uma exceção:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("p.zip", data);
```

**O acesso ao caminho 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\p.zip' foi negado.**

Estou realizando teste em localhost, não testei no servidor, pois tenho que desenvolver primeiro a solução por completa.

Perguntas 
O que representa **"./g"** ?

Posso realizar teste desta aplicação em **localhost** ?

Comment: Qual o erro? o que está acontecendo que não está conseguindo?

Comment: Fiz a edição na minha resposta, porque, realmente falou dizer em qual local quer salvar e depois descompactar os zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) e o [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Compression.ZipFile/4.3.0) instalação via [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/), com um exemplo minimo:

```
HttpClient web = new HttpClient();
string url = "http://www.caixa.gov.br/Downloads/";
url += "licitacoes-e-fornecedores-consultas-publicas/TR_Nova_Instantanea_v2.zip";
byte[] data = await web.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("zip/p.zip"), data);
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(Server.MapPath("zip/p.zip"), Server.MapPath("descompacta/"));
```

***Observação:*** `zip/` e `descompacta/` são **diretórios** válidos na sua aplicação *Web*.