# Erro de leitura arquivo HTM para conversão HTML para arquivo JSON

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, json, conversão-de-tipo

Neste
[Tópico que criei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/251096/rotina-para-baixar-e-descompactar-arquivo-zip-no-pr%C3%B3prio-servidor/251119#251119)

Foi perguntado como baixar arquivo zip do servidor da Caixa e descompacta-lo em meu serviço de hospedagem **que ocorre perfeitamente**.

Apos os eventos anteriores descrito, quero fazer a leitura do html, mas esta dando erro de localização do arquivo;

**Não foi possível localizar uma parte do caminho 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Content\descompacta\D_MEGA.HTM'.**

O erro ocorre nesta linha:

```
string page = webClient.DownloadString("Content/descompacta/D_MEGA.HTM");
```

**Quero fazer a leitura do HTML e converte-lo em JSON**

**Código abaixo da função que estou desenvolvendo, gostaria da analise também para ver se não há redundância em relação às Classes HttpClient e WebClient**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
            HttpClient web = new HttpClient();
            string url = "http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/";
            url += "loterias/D_megase.zip";
            byte[] data = await web.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("Content/zip/megasena.zip"), data);
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(Server.MapPath("Content/zip/megasena.zip"), Server.MapPath("Content/descompacta/"));

            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            string page = webClient.DownloadString("Content/descompacta/D_MEGA.HTM");

            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(page);

            List<List<string>> table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='mydata']")
                        .Descendants("tr")
                        .Skip(1)
                        .Where(tr => tr.Elements("td").Count() > 1)
                        .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim()).ToList())
                        .ToList();


            return View();
        }
```